# User listed in group but not in getent passwd

Tags: users, ldap, getent

On a specific machine with both local users and LDAP users, there is a user that is listed under `getent group foo` (let's say the user `jdoe` is listed), but when doing `getent passwd jdoe` I get no output. Attempting `sudo su jdoe` doesn't work either.

Using the command `members -t foo` I found out the user is only listed as a secondary member of the group, although I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Does anyone know how I can find out how this seemingly nonexistent user ended up in this user group? To clarify, the listed user is in no way related to a system user, and it doesn't seem to be listed anywhere under locally created users.

Something that might be a possibility: is it possible this is being caused by someone who previously had a user account named `jdoe`, whose account since has been renamed or deleted? And if so, how can I find this out?

This is my `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:         compat ldap systemd
group:          compat ldap systemd
shadow:         compat ldap

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

It is pretty much the default configuration with LDAP included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen when the LDAP database has a `PosixGroup` `foo` with attribute `memberUid` with value `jdoe`
The user might or might not exist, but the username does exist in the `PosixGroup` `foo`

This might be a security risk, when a (different) user with username `jdoe` is added to the LDAP-database again, when you do not want the user to be part of `foo`.